# Drawing with opposing (reverse) colors on a winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, drawing

We have a winforms app (Framework v4) that shows an image (via PictureBox) on the screen and allows selection of a rectangular region on that image. During and after the image selection, we show the boundary of the selected area. This is currently done via a `DrawRectangle` call.

The problem is how to choose the color of this rectangle. Regardless of the chosen color, it is always possible that it will blend into the background (the image). Microsoft paint handles this very well by reversing the colors dynamically on the "selection rectangle". This suits very well to our application, but I have no idea how to do it in winforms.

I also looked around to see if there's a dash-style that would allow two colors to be used (so that I could specify black and white as these colors, making it visible no matter what the background colors are), but I could not find anything of this sort.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: You would do exactly what Microsoft Paint does, look at the background image, and determine color you should be using. Please note there are some colors where their opposing color is th emself. I would look at the open source project Paint.NET for ideas. This has nothing to do with WinForms, the real solution is to extend your own abilities, the default methods won't achieve what you want.

Comment: @Ramhound: Well, the solution needs to be implemented in Winforms, so the solution has to have something to do with it. Even if I look at the background image, I am not sure how to utilize this information with the APIs in the winforms drawing functions. I also looked at Paint.Net's license. It does not allow creating derivative works, so I am not sure if it is a good idea to look at its source code and "get inspired". PS: Thanks for the tip about colors having opposites as themselves. I will consider that while working on a solution.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `ControlPaint` methods to paint a reversible rectangle/frame

`ControlPaint.FillReversibleRectangle` [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.fillreversiblerectangle.aspx)

and

`ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame` [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawreversibleframe.aspx)

here is a little pseudo code method example

```
private void DrawReversibleRectangle(int x, int y) {
  // Hide the previous rectangle by calling the methods with the same parameters.
  var rect = GetSelectionRectangle(this.PointToScreen(this.reversibleRectStartPoint), this.PointToScreen(this.reversibleRectEndPoint));
  ControlPaint.FillReversibleRectangle(rect, Color.Black);
  ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(rect, Color.Black, FrameStyle.Dashed);
  this.reversibleRectEndPoint = new Point(x, y);
  // Draw the new rectangle by calling
  rect = GetSelectionRectangle(this.PointToScreen(this.reversibleRectStartPoint), this.PointToScreen(this.reversibleRectEndPoint));
  ControlPaint.FillReversibleRectangle(rect, Color.Black);
  ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(rect, Color.Black, FrameStyle.Dashed);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about `DrawReversibleFrame`. I could draw the rectangle but then it disappears. I am doing the drawing in the `Paint` method of the `PictureBox`. Is this wrong?

Comment: try calling the DrawReversibleRectangle method at the mouse move event (with storing the start at mouse down, etc)

Answer (score 2):

You mention an alternative solution would be to draw a dashed line in two colors, black and white, so that it would be visible on any background.

Fake this by drawing solid line in one color (e.g. black), then draw a dashed line in the other color (e.g. white).

Idea and code from: http://csharphelper.com/blog/2012/09/draw-two-colored-dashed-lines-that-are-visible-on-any-background-in-c/

```
using (Pen pen1 = new Pen(Color.Black, 2))
{
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen1, rect);
}
using (Pen pen2 = new Pen(Color.White, 2))
{
    pen2.DashPattern = new float[] { 5, 5 };
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen2, rect);
}
```